# Background image not rendering properly in iphone landscape orientation for my mobile web application using jquerymobile?

Tags: iphone, coding-style, background, landscape, jquery-mobile

I am developing a web application using jquerymobile, I set the page style width and height as 100%. I have the background image for that page and also set the backgroundimage to repeat.

On the iPhone, in portrait mode, the background occupies the full screen size, but when I change to landscape mode I am getting whitespace(without bg) in the bottom of the screen. It is only on the iPhone that I have this issue. I have also tested on android, ipad annd blackberry devices. On all these devices both orientation have the background image perfectly occupy the full screen according to the controls.

Has anybody faced this problem? Or can give me some suggestion for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am get resolved in this issues. I am just removed height and width of the page and the problem is solved, that mean i am setting width and height as 100% so when controls went out of that screen i am getting that issues, so removed the specification that get resolved but after removing that same  issue  reflect in ipad for that  am edited the jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css file in that they set max height of landscape and portrait i just removed both height ,and all my problem get solved.

Thanks for your response naugtur.

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas:

1. Try setting the background to body, not page if you can,
2. Define background for both classes

> ```
>  .portrait yourelement {
>   /* the same bg declaration */
>  }
>  .landscape yourelement {
>   /* the same bg declaration */
>  }
> ```